# Parameterisation of Curve in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Background: I've started reading Miles' "Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry" ([Link](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/MA4A5/UAG.pdf)) recently though struggling a lot.

I'm stuck at processing the following paragraph...

### Sec. 1.7 Parametrisation of a conic

[image]

#### Corollary 1.6

[image]

### Here is my question list;

1. How can we picture the new coordinates $(X+Z, Y, Z-X)$? I tried to visualise it on some 3D visualiser, eg., GeoGebra, but it gives me error as it's not a function...
2. What are the variables $U, V$? Can I think of it as some form of parameteric functions controlled by a variable like $t$?
3. To understand the bit `$C$ is projectively equivalent to the curve $(XZ = Y^2)$`, I graphed C and the curve [here](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/ebwxqd4b) but I can't seem to find what the equivalence means....

Sorry for listing questions but can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is not easy to visualize; this is a coordinate transformation $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. In fact, this is a linear transformation. Can you find the matrix representing it? Examples of these kinds of transformations include dilations and rotations
2. $U$ and $V$ represent real numbers so that $(U, V)$ is a point of $\mathbb{P}^1$. (That it, $U$ and $V$ are not both zero.) The parametrization is telling you, for example, that $\Phi((1,2)) = (1, 2, 4)$.
3. There is a mistake in your visualization. In particular, $eq2$ should be $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ instead of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Once you make this change, it'll look quite possible to move one cone to the other using rotations and dilations.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Daniel!
This makes sense! and thank you for suggesting the fix as well!